# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre scope.$eval y eval?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Mirando en el código fuente de Angular.js, me encontré con que hay varios `scope.$eval` que se utilizan para evaluar expresiones. Encontré la definición del método:

```
  $eval: function(expr, locals) {
    return $parse(expr)(this, locals);
  }
```

Que a su vez me llevó a `$parse` (y a `parseProvider`) que parece que convierte expresiones a funciones y las ejecuta.

Según la [documentación de Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) (extracto traducido por mí):

> ### `$eval([expression], [locals]);`
>
> Ejecuta la expresión en el entorno actual y devuelve el resultado. Cualquier excepción en la expresión es propagada (no detectada). Es útil para evaluar expresiones en AngularJS.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `scope.$eval` en Angular y `eval` en JavaScript puro? ¿Por qué no se usa `eval` directamente?

Comment: Related: [Angular.js: How does $eval work and why is it different from vanilla eval?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15671573/3045491)

Comment: Maybe: http://webiks.com/the-war-of-good-vs-eval-or-eval-vs-eval/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diferencia entre `$eval` y `eval` radica en el tipo de expresiones que evalúan: `eval` ejecuta JavaScript, mientras que `$eval` (y `$parse`) ejecuta expresiones de AngularJS.

Las expresiones de AngularJS son pequeños trozos de código que parecen JavaScript y que van en los *bindings* (p.e. `<span title="{{ attrBinding }}">{{ textBinding }}</span>`) o en atributos de directiva (p.e. `ng-click="functionExpression()"`) y que se procesan con el servicio `$parse`.

No son exactamente JavaScript sino un mini-lenguaje parecido a JavaScript, lo que ayuda a limitar qué cosas se van a evaluar (proporcionando más seguridad), permite añadir cosas específicas de AngularJS (como por ejemplo los filtros), y presenta un mejor rendimiento (más rápidas).

Éstas son algunas de las diferencias entre las expresiones en JavaScript y las expresiones de AngularJS, por lo tanto diferencias entre `eval` y `$eval` respectivamente (traducción de la [documentación en inglés](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions)):

- **Contexto**: en JavaScript, las expresiones se evalúan sobre la `window` global; mientras que en Angular las expresiones se evalúan contra el objeto `scope`.
- **Tolerancia**: en Javascript, si evalúas una propiedad indefinida, se genera un error de referencia o de tipo; en AngularJS, se "perdona" y se devuelve `undefined` o `null`.
- **Filtros**: En las expresiones de AngularJS puedes usar filtros para formatear los datos ante de mostrarlos.
- **Sentencias de control de flujo**: En las expresiones de AngularJS no se pueden utilizar condicionales, bucles o excepciones, que sí se pueden evaluar en JavaScript con `eval`.
- **Declaración de funciones**: No se pueden declarar funciones en una expresión de AngularJS, ni siquiera dentro de la directiva `ng-init`.
- **Expresiones regulares**: No se pueden crear expresiones regulares en una expresión de AngularJS.
- **Creación de objetos**: No se puede usar el operador `new` en una expresión de AngularJS.
- **Limitación de operadores**: No se pueden usar operadores de Bitwise, `,` o `void` en una expresión de AngularJS.

Si quieres evaluar código JavaScript más complejo, deberías crear un método en el controlador y llamar a ese método desde la vista. Si quieres hacer un `eval()` de una expresión de AngularJS, usa el método `$eval()`.

---

Más información:

- [Documentación oficial de AngularJS para `$eval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) (en inglés)
- [Documentación oficial de AngularJS sobre expresiones](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) (en inglés)
- [StackOverflow: How does $eval work and why is it different from vanilla eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671471/angular-js-how-does-eval-work-and-why-is-it-different-from-vanilla-eval/) (en inglés)
- [The war of good vs. $eval (or eval vs. $eval)](http://webiks.com/the-war-of-good-vs-eval-or-eval-vs-eval/) (en inglés)